# Is the NativeX iOS SDK thread-safe?

Tags: ios, thread-safety, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I'm trying to run a [NativeX](https://github.com/nativex/NativeX-iOS-SDK) fetchAd call inside of GCD `dispatch_async` without success. Is the **NativeX** lib thread-safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NativeX support say that is is thread-safe